# full width banner size on extra large screen device (width>1366px)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML

```
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div id="mainSlide" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#mainSlide" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <li data-target="#mainSlide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#mainSlide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner img-responsive">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="nature1">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="nature2">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="nature3">
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainSlide" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainSlide" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-padding{
  padding: 0px;
}
.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Problem

[image: Screenshot]

As it can be seen in the banner it shows abnormally on larger screen,how can it be fixed.On smaller screen (<=1366px) banner works fine.How to fix this,thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: maybe with object-fit:fill ?

Comment: or maybe adding the class `img-responsive` and using css `media-queries`

Comment: have you got your website live? if so could you please share the link?

Comment: not yet @Matt, it's actually a small college project for my niece.And I have added img-responsive to carousel class(line 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to the `<img>` preferably using a class.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/jeQOmG

let me know if this isn't what you were after

Comment: The css selector can be `.item img` for example.

Comment: This is true ^^^

Comment: @CodeBoyCode  Indeed that is what i was missing, it was a mistake on my part to think image would scale to it's immediate previous container.